# Neo4J: Return only the candidates, not all the combinations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, reduce

Consider a Cypher query in the following form:

`MATCH a-->b,a-->c,a-->d WHERE [some conditions on a, b, c and d] RETURN id(a),id(b),id(c),id(d)`

The query above, probably as expected, will return all the combinations of candidate nodes for a, b, c, and d. So, for instance, if there are three candidates for b and four candidates for c, the total number of rows returned by the query will be 3 x 4 = 12. How can it be adjusted so the different matching nodes for each alias (a to d) is returned only once?

The following query is not a valid one, but should clarify what I have in mind:

`MATCH a-->b,a-->c,a-->d WHERE [some conditions on a, b, c and d] RETURN distinct id(a), distinct id(b), distinct id(c), distinct id(d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use distinct aggregation.

```
MATCH a-->b,a-->c,a-->d 
WHERE [some conditions on a, b, c and d] 
RETURN collect(distinct id(a)) as ids_a,collect(distinct id(b)) as ids_b,
       collect(distinct id(c)) as ids_c,collect(distinct id(d)) as ids_d;
```

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you Michael.